# I cannot see a feedback in Drupal's Quiz module (Drupal 7, Quiz version 7.x-5.2)

Tags: drupal, feedback

I am using Drupal 7.
I am using Drupal's **Quiz** module version 7.x-5.2 and only an Admin can see each "Question's feedback" in the quiz results view/page.
Everything else works perfectly:
In the quiz results view/page, I can see:

1. The question
2. The option/answer that the user chose
3. The grade for each question
4. But only an admin can see each Question's feedback in the results.

I am also using Content Access version 7.x-1.2-beta2 and in the ROLE BASED ACCESS CONTROL SETTINGS, everything seems to be set properly.

I "played" a bit with the grade, summary, Feedback table and I manage to move each one of them in the Quiz results display and I also manage to remove each one of them out of the Quiz results display and then bring it back.
Every such configuration change that I make is visible to all roles, but the only "stubborn one" is the Question's feedback. - Only an Admin can view it.

One more thing:
When I enable all users to be able to "Edit any quiz content", then all users can see the question's feedback (for every question) , but this is obviously not what want. I cannot allow all users to edit any content...

Just to be on the safe side, what I really want in this case is to provide the following:
After a regular user finished answering a whole test/quiz, I want him/her to view:

1. all the questions in a list/table (this works well)
2. For each question, I want them to see their score, e.g.: 0 of 1 or 1 of 1 (this works well).
3. For each question, I want them to see their answer (this works well).
4. For each question, I want them to see the right answer (this works only for admin users or for users who have "Edit any quiz content" enabled).
5. For each question, I want them to see the question's feedback, where I wrote an explanation of how to solve the question. (this works only for admin users or for users who have "Edit any quiz content" enabled).

How do I enable all users to see the question's feedback ?

I am not sure it's related, but in QuizResultAnswerController.class.inc of Quiz module version 7.x-5.2 I saw the following:

**if ($instance->canReview('question_feedback')) {**

I think (but not sure...) that this piece of code "decides" not to display the question_feedback for regular users.

I don't understand why does this feature require someone who can review and/or how do I enable someone to be a viewer/reviewer of the results without enabling him/her to change the content.

Please help me. This is very important !

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
Click [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz/issues/2953990) to view it on Drupal's site.